# Swiftui animation calendar dates

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

In my app I want to show the passage of time by having a "calendar" transition from one date to the next, to the next, to the next, etc. So, for example, if I want to show the date transitioning from the 18th, to the 19th, to the 20th, I will show 18 for 1 second, then fade that out, fade in 19, fade that out, then fade in 20.

I have the following to show one date animating to the next (e.g. 18 > 19th):

```
struct Calendar: View {
    @State var date:  String

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Spacer()
        ZStack {
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)

        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            .fill(Color.red)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .offset(y: 160)
            .clipped()
            .offset(y: -160)
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .offset(y: 160)
                    .clipped()
                    .offset(y: -160)
            
Text(date).font(.system(size: 70.0))
                .offset(y: 20)
                    
           
        }
           
            Spacer()
            
            Spacer()

        }.padding()
        }
}
```

and I call this in my code using:

```
 ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    ZStack {
                        
                        
                        if showseconddate == false {
                            Calendar(date: "18").animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0))
                                .transition(.opacity)
                        }
                        if showseconddate == true {
                            Calendar(date: "19").animation(.easeInOut(duration: 1.0))
                                .transition(.opacity)
                          
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        
                    }
                    
                }.onAppear {
                    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true) { timer in
                        
                        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.5)) {
                            self.showseconddate.toggle()
                            self.showfirstdate.toggle() }
                        
                        timer.invalidate()
                        
                    }
                }
                
            }
```

This all works as intended, but I'm struggling to then expand this to a case where I want to show it transitioning through multiple dates, such as 18 > 19 >20 >21 etc. Does anyone know how to expand this, or to use an alternative solution? Any solution must fade out the old date, then fade in the new date. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a relatively compact solution. Instead of relying on `Bool` values, it cycles through an array:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    private var dates = ["18","19","20","21","22"]
    @State private var dateIndex = 0
    
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View{
        ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                ZStack {
                    Calendar(date: dates[dateIndex])
                        .transition(.opacity)
                        .id("date-\(dateIndex)")
                    Spacer()
                }
            }.onReceive(timer) { _ in
                var newIndex = dateIndex + 1
                if newIndex == dates.count { newIndex = 0 }
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5)) {
                    dateIndex = newIndex
                }
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I’ll try this over the weekend and let you know how I get on.

Comment: Did this work for you?

Comment: It did, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had reworked your code to get the animations running, I felt it was a bit annoying to watch the entire calendar flash, so I reworked it into a `CalendarPage` (I renamed Calendar to CalendarPage because Calendar is a Type in Swift) and `CalendarView` that takes the date and overlays it on the page.

CalendarPage is your Calendar with the `date` var and `Text()` removed:

```
struct CalendarPage: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .fill(Color.red)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .offset(y: 160)
                    .clipped()
                    .offset(y: -160)
                
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 2)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .offset(y: 160)
                    .clipped()
                    .offset(y: -160)
            }
            Spacer()
            
            Spacer()
        }.padding()
    }
}
```

CalendarView uses the timer to increment your dates until you reach the `endDate`, and it only effects the opacity of the date itself, not the whole calendar:

```
struct CalendarView: View {
    
    @State var date: Int = 0
    @State var animate = false
    @State var calendarSize: CGFloat = 20
    let endDate = 31
    
    // This keeps the font size consistent regardless of the size of the calendar
    var fontSize: CGFloat {
        calendarSize * 0.45
    }
    
    private let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    
    var body: some View {
        CalendarPage(date: date.description)
            .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                VStack {
                    Text(date.description)
                        .font(.system(size: fontSize))
                        .opacity(animate ? 1 : 0)
                }
                .frame(height: calendarSize * 0.8)
            }
        
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            .readSize(onChange: { size in
                calendarSize = min(size.width, size.height)
            })
            .onReceive(timer) { _ in
                date += 1
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.3)) {
                    animate = true
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.75) {
                    if date != endDate {
                        withAnimation(.linear(duration: 0.2)) {
                            animate = false
                        }
                    } else {
                        timer.upstream.connect().cancel()
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

I also used a preference key to compute the height of the `CalendarPage` (though I could have hard coded it) using this `View` extension from [FiveStars blog](https://www.fivestars.blog/articles/swiftui-share-layout-information/)

```
extension View {
    func readSize(onChange: @escaping (CGSize) -> Void) -> some View {
        background(
            GeometryReader { geometryProxy in
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: SizePreferenceKey.self, value: geometryProxy.size)
            }
        )
            .onPreferenceChange(SizePreferenceKey.self, perform: onChange)
    }
}

fileprivate struct SizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGSize = .zero
    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I’ll try this over the weekend and let you know how I get on.